# Django query set filter

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to create a query set that filters all the cars hired by a user.
the car hire model has a foreignkey which stores the user's ID when a car is hired

My current solution is like this, where I get current users ID and then try filtering the Cars database against the user's ID.

view.py:

```
def view_hire(request):
  current_users_id = request.user.id
  car_hired = Cars_hired.objects.filter(user_id__in=current_users_id) 
  args = 
  {
      'car_hired': car_hired,
  }
```

Models

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.id)

class car_hired(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(help_text='Date of booking')
    end_time = models.DateField(help_text='Date of booking')


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

However, I can't seem to get this to work and I am getting the error "'int' object is not iterable"

I would like to create a query set that returns the row of data that matches the query

for example, if the current user's id is 10 I would like to get all the cars hired by the user. All the data stored in the rows where car_hirer_is == 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is causing the error:

```
...(user_id__in=current_users_id)
```

When you add the **__in** part it makes django think that current_users_id is an iterable but `current_users_id = request.user.id` is a single id. To make it work change it to:

```
def view_hire(request):
  current_users_id = request.user.id
  car_hired = Cars_hired.objects.filter(customer__user_id=current_users_id)
```

I would also reconsider the names of the variables (current_user_id instead of current_users_id and cars_hired instead of car_hired).

Comment: I printed the current_user_id to console to double check if it's working, which = 14
and then printed the args {'hires': <QuerySet []>} and got a empty set. However, there is a user with a user_id 14 present in the car hire model/database

Comment: can you post User model and Cars_hired mode?